gradient becomes none after apply mask on trainable variable
When I implement the following code, gradient of x becomes none after apply mask on trainable variable. After removed the mask the gradient is able to be calculated. I am wondering what the reason of it.
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu')
x = tf.Variable([[1., 2., 3.]], name = "tfv", trainable=True)
mask = tf.constant([0., 1., 0.], shape = (3,1))
x_ = x@mask
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  # Forward pass
  y = layer(x_)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)

# Calculate gradients with respect to every trainable variable
grad = tape.gradient(loss, [layer.trainable_variables, x])

the output of grad is
[[<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[0.       , 5.2745185]], dtype=float32)>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([0.       , 2.6372592], dtype=float32)>],
 None]

after I remove the mask
layer = tf.keras.layers.Dense(2, activation='relu')
x = tf.Variable([[1., 2., 3.]], name = "tfv", trainable=True)
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  # Forward pass
  y = layer(x)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)

# Calculate gradients with respect to every trainable variable
grad = tape.gradient(loss, [layer.trainable_variables,x])

the output of gradient is
[[<tf.Tensor: shape=(3, 2), dtype=float32, numpy=
  array([[1.2404386, 3.1709769],
         [2.4808772, 6.3419538],
         [3.7213159, 9.512931 ]], dtype=float32)>,
  <tf.Tensor: shape=(2,), dtype=float32, numpy=array([1.2404386, 3.1709769], dtype=float32)>],
 <tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 3), dtype=float32, numpy=array([[2.8783302 , 0.38053298, 2.651462  ]], dtype=float32)>]


The reason is most likely that you want the gradient w.r.t. x, but you multiply x with the mask outside the GradientTape. Therefore, the tape never records the gradients back to x, but only to x_. This is also the reason that your second example works. There, you define x and then every operation on x is inside the GradientTape.
The solution is to just move x@mask inside the with block:
with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
  x_ = x@mask
  # Forward pass
  y = layer(x_)
  loss = tf.reduce_mean(y**2)

This way, the tape knows the relation between x and x_.
